How put multiple spaces in an html SELECT tag?
I've got a web form and for the phone number entry, I'm listing three character countries and their calling codes inside a select tag like:
ARG +54
MOZ +258
USA +1

But I'd like to clean up its display so the calling codes are right justified and look like:
ARG  +54
MOZ +258
USA   +1

The longest dialing code is 5 characters so I was going to add spaces for the code length - 5.  Spaces, of course, are compressed by the browser to one space.  Same thing happens inside the SELECT.  So, no problem, I'll just add enough &nbsp; tags to make up the necessary number of spaces. But it displays:
ARG&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+54

So, now the SELECT options are treated as text! Tried <pre>...</pre> in the options... showed the <pre>.  Put <pre> outside the SELECT.  Styled the SELECT with white-space:pre, pre-line, pre-wrap, normal, etc. and no joy.
I'd really like to know if there is a way to right justify the dialing codes within the select options.

I was able to achieve the result using a little code and the Unicode non-breaking space, \u00A0:
var spaces = 6 - o.phonePrefix.length;
var s = '\u00A0'.repeat(spaces) + o.phonePrefix;
select.options[select.length] = new Option(o.code + s, o.phonePrefix); 

And a little CSS, monospace and pre:
 <select style="font-family:monospace;white-space:pre;">

Monospace ensures the characters are the same width and pre ensures spaces are preserved in the select.
